# Symfony 2.8 injecting twig

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, model

Pre-note: I am learning Symfony from a Drupal 7 background.

I have created a custom model (although I think they are called services in Symfony from what I have read), and would like it to render an array via twig into a variable.

I found this link, and thought that this injection approach would do the trick:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html

Sadly, I and up with the below error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Model\Newsletter::__construct() must be an instance of
>   AppBundle\Model\Twig_Environment, none given, called in
>   /home/dan/working_files/symfony-playground/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
>   on line 130

So, I am wondering what is an acceptable approach so I can use twig within my custom model/service/class?

If it is of use, here is some of my code for reference:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    appbundle.newsletter:
        class: AppBundle\Model\Newsletter
        arguments: ['@twig']
```

**src/AppBundle/Model/Newsletter.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Model;

class Newsletter
{
    private $twig;
    public function __construct(Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }
}
```

**Calling my model**

```
$newsletter = new Newsletter();
```

Comment: you should call your model as service to inject dependencies, if you calling it in controller you can get service like this `$newsletter = $this->get('appbundle.newsletter');`

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean.  The line `$newsletter = new Newsletter();` is being called from `DefaultController.php` at the moment.

Comment: so controller has helper to get services. Simple calling `$this->get('service_name');` will get you service with dependencies injected. If you calling class with `new ClassName()` then you have to manually pass twig instance to class constructor.

Comment: Ah fantastic, a mixture of this and the comment from Alessandro have together helped to resolve this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change twig with EngineInterface like this:

```
services:
    appbundle.newsletter:
        class: AppBundle\Model\Newsletter
        arguments: ['@templating']
```

And

```
namespace AppBundle\Model;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

class Newsletter
{
    private $twig;
    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->twig = $templating;
    }
}
```

After you need o call the service:

```
$this->get('service_name');
```

Comment: Changing this did not seem to resolve the issue sadly

Comment: So there were 2 issues.  One was switching to EngineInterface, and the other was changing how I called my Model so instead I used `$this->get('service_name');`

Comment: Great glad to helped you so! :)

Comment: I update the answer with the miss part of the service

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$newsletter = new Newsletter();` you're not accessing the service through the dependency injection container, ignoring the service definition you did.

To leverage the DIC and have your dependencies like `@twig` injected on your service, you should grab the service instance using the service container. To do that on a Symfony controller you can do it like this:

```
$newsletter = $this->get('appbundle.newsletter');
```

`@twig` is gonna be injected in your service as defined on the yaml file and it is shared between every place you use your service again through the container.